# how to create a sticker App and send them to WhatsApp or any messenger using JS Frameworks like ionic or React native?

Tags: angular, react-native, ionic-framework

I wanted to create a Hybrid App using Ionic/React native. In my application, I am going to create stickers and I wanted to upload those stickers to WhatsUp. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm interested in this topic.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-whatsapp-stickers

Comment: @kunwar97 Thanks, I will try with this package.

Comment: @Anji have you solved it? I'm having the same question for ionic

Comment: @Anji have you tried in react native ? Please guide me about this how can i achieve this functionality.

Comment: @DivyataChauhan  I didn't found any solution to do this functionality. hence I have stopped it for some time.

Answer (score 8):

That's not how Whatsapp stickers work, they're not uploaded to Whatsapp.

> If you'd like to create your own stickers for WhatsApp, you can
>   package them in an Android or iOS app. You can publish your sticker
>   app like any other app to the Google Play Store or Apple App Store,
>   and users who download and install your app will be able to start
>   sending those stickers right away from within WhatsApp.

You can check the full specifications of creating Whatsapp stickers posted by Whatsapp [here](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000226).

They've even published native app samples for both Android & IOS [here](https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers) so you can replicate them on whatever technology you want to use.