# how to import whatsapp stickers using ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I have looking for the solution to build an ionic base WhatsApp sticker importing app. I have refer the following and still no luck

[how to create a sticker App and send them to WhatsApp or any messenger using JS Frameworks like ionic or React native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57405458/how-to-create-a-sticker-app-and-send-them-to-whatsapp-or-any-messenger-using-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my issue back then using https://github.com/Wiseonesoft/cordova-whatsapp-sticker-plugin

plugin. In the read me file, H4ad has described the process very well.

Answer (score 1):

As a general idea, you need to make an app structure similar to general editing photo app, but instead the extension of the image that that will be generated should be webp , in general these stickers can be found in whatsapp folder/media/whatsapp stickers . So all what is needed that you can make small gallery within your application, and per item you create, on click should be an option add to whatsapp which will take these content to whatsapp stickers folder and thus appear in the app and become useable stickers .

**Tips for main sticker:**

```
 - Each sticker is an image that has a transparent background.     

 - Stickers must be exactly 512x512 pixels.

 - Each sticker must be less than 100 KB.  

 - There should be a 16-pixel margin between the actual sticker image and the edge of the 512x512 pixel canvas.
```

**Tips for small sticker preview:**

```
 - This image should be 96x96 pixels and must be less than 50 KB.
```

**Github reposatory for whatsapp sticker creation in android and ios so you can get benefit on how to create your project in **Ionic**:**
[https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers](http://Whatapp%20Stickers)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but in my case, I'm already having the sticker pack, I just don't know how to import those stickers to WhatsApp. I have already referred the   link you have provided and still no luck